# Increase java output file size

Tags: java, size

I want to create some test java files with different sizes (100kb-500kb). In that case I am modifying simple hello world.

**The program will be never executed** so creating objects inside class wont be called.

I'd like to create some constants like in C/C++ language that will be saved in file, not in runtime memory

I am working with midlet library and somehow I cant create static/final variables outside the class.

```
package HelloWorld;

import javax.microedition.midlet.*;

//cant create consts here?

public class HelloWorld extends MIDlet {


public HelloWorld() {
    System.out.println("Constructor"); 
}

public void startApp() throws MIDletStateChangeException {
    System.out.println("startApp");
    System.out.println("\nHello World\n");
    destroyApp(true);   
}

public void pauseApp() {
    System.out.println("pauseApp()");
}

public void destroyApp(boolean cond) {
    System.out.println("destroyApp(" + cond + ")");
    notifyDestroyed();
}

//public String[][][] toppings = new String[200000][200000][20000];
}
```

Whats the simple and effective way to increase size of java build output file? The output format will be .jrc

Comment: What do you mean by 'inition'?

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume to start with that you are talking about the size of ".class" files.

> Does initialization of that multi-vector in HellWorld class constructor will do it?

Actually, no.  That initialization is actually performed by a single bytecode instruction.  Irrespective of the size of the array.  You can make your ".class" bigger by adding dimensions to the array, but not enough to generate *large* ".class" files.

> Isnt it called after program start?

Yes it is ... but that doesn't affect the size of the class file.

---

Now if you are talking about the amount of memory needed to *run* the program, then an array of that size *will* take a lot of memory:

- one `String[][][]` array with 200,000 elements for the first dimension
- 200,000 `String[][]` arrays with 200,000 elements for the second dimension
- 40,000,000,000 `String[]` arrays with 20,000 elements for the third dimension.

That is a huge amount of memory.   But the memory is only allocated at runtime.  So much memory that your program won't run on a typical laptop / desktop.

(Which leads me to think that this is not what you are asking about!)

As I said, the ".class" file will be tiny, since the allocation performed using a single bytecode instruction ... with 3 operands: one for each dimension.

---

> Whats the simple and effective way to increase size of java build output file?

Classes with lots of large methods or constructors.

Classes with lots of distinct literal strings (preferably large).

However, be aware that the class file format imposes some limits on these things; see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se9/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.11

---

> I am working with midlet library and somehow I cant create static/final variables outside the class.

That's because Java doesn't allow it.  All variables must be declared inside classes (or interfaces).   Java is different to C / C++ in many respects, and this is just one of them.

I suggest that you take the time to read a Java tutorial or textbook, rather than guessing how the language works based on knowledge of C and C++.

Comment: Creating super-long string like `string a = "asdsadasd[...]"` doesnt affect the output file jrc size. I cant also define it outside the class

Comment: What is a "jrc size"?   *"I cant also define it outside the class"*.  Obviously not.  Your Java source code needs to be valid source code.  Just about everything in Java must go inside a class.

Answer (score 0):

All you did was declare an array, you didn't assign any values, so you're still writing a "null."

Have a look at the [Arrays.fill()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) documentation.  Also try asking a question that includes some code with a solution that can be worked because this is kind of vague, and you're also misunderstanding how [creating objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html) works in java.